# How to setup remote modal in Bootstrap 5 CS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'am trying to get a remote modal window working in Bootstrap 5 c# mvc.

I have an endpoint for the modal partial view setup correctly.

As per [this post](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36086) on Github, all you have to do is call some javascript. However it does not specify the elements.

I tried calling both the div for the modal and the button with a href itself.

In the console I am getting an Illegal invocation error:
[image]

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" href="https://localhost:7023/Pokus/PokusModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modal-data" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1">
    <!-- Completes the modal component here -->
</div>

<script>
    const modal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')

    modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

        const link = event.relatedTarget.getAttribute('href');
        const modalData = document.querySelector('.modal-data');

        fetch(link).then(res => res.text()).then(html => {
            modalData.innerHTML = html;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Did the show.bs.modal event change?

How do I setup the modal to load using the href?

Comment: The error isn't caused by the JS code in your question, it's an internal bootstrap error and it happens anyway even if you remove that code: https://jsfiddle.net/6g4a1vsu/2/. It goes away if you add the required HTML structure within the modal (as per the examples in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#examples): https://jsfiddle.net/6g4a1vsu/3/ . Basically the error is because bootstrap can't find the items it's expecting within the modal.

Comment: I understand that, but does that mean a remote modal using href is no longer possible? The github post is just 8 months ago. It seemed doable to me with the event. Did the show.bs.modal event change? I'am updating an old application from bs3 to bs5 so I cannot rework the modals.

Comment: No it doesn't, I don't think. Because when you run `modalData.innerHTML = html` it'll just overwrite whatever was inside the modal to begin with. But by that time the modal is already open so it won't matter. The only issue might come if you then close and try to re-open it, I guess. I suggest ensuring what's served from the remote site is compatible with the structure bootstrap expects. If that's not possible, then maybe don't use bootstrap to do the modal - it's not very difficult to make your own, or find another example code on the net to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working like so:

In my layout I have:

```
<div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-container" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

            const modal = document.getElementById('modal-container')

            modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

                const link = event.relatedTarget.getAttribute('href');
                const modalData = document.querySelector('#modal-container');

                fetch(link).then(res => res.text()).then(html => {

                    modalData.innerHTML = html;

                    //if you want your modal to include scripts:
                    const scripts = modalData.getElementsByTagName('script');

                    for (var n = 0; n < scripts.length; n++)
                        eval(scripts[n].innerHTML);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Then I have any number of buttons, each pointing to an endpoint with their modal:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-target="#modal-container" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="/YourController/SomeAction/">Remove</a>
```

And your modal view looks like this:

```
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Loading...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You can even include a script with the modal view, just mind the security concerns of using eval()!